# Exception in PHPMailer stops the whole script instead of just continuing

Tags: php, exception, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer for a newsletter sending job. Sometimes it happens that an attachment or some other details are not right for one specific email recipient. In this case it throws an Exception which I write into my own logfile and that is great because it often clearly states what's wrong.

The Problem is, that the complete script stops and all the further emails which might have proper settings are not sent.

How do I configure it in order to not stop the complete script when PHPMailer throws an Exception and just continue until all the emails in the for loop with proper settings are being sent?

```
read * from email_receipients
for each {


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //SMTP settings
    //..

    
    $mail->Subject = $mailbody_subject;
    $mail->Body    = $mailbody_html;
    $mail->AltBody = $mailbody_text;
    $mail->send();

    
} catch (phpmailerException $ep) {
    $ep_mail_send_message = $ep->getMessage();
    $ep_mail_send_code = $ep->getCode();    

    //writes the $ep error messages to a log file
    
    
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $e_mail_send_message = $e->getMessage();
    $e_mail_send_code = $e->getCode();

    //writes the $e error messages to a log file

}

} //closes the for each loop
```

Comment: This suggests that it throws an exception that you’re not catching – can you show the error it stops on? Your code isn’t very efficient as it makes a new instance and connection every time round the loop. Look at the PHPMailer mailing list example for how to do this better.

Comment: Kindly provide error / exception details.

Comment: try/catch is the way to stop an exception halting the script. So probably this exception is occurring outside your existing try/catch. If you need help with this, please provide the full exception details and tell us which line of your code it occurs on.